# Checking a pattern in a file

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to check for a pattern in a file, and if the pattern cannot be found, print a warning or something. The file has about 100 lines.

Here is the code I tried.

```
file = file.open("file_tobe_checked", "r")
while (line=file.get)
  if (line =~ /Copyright \W+ \d\d\d\d/).nil?  # the pattern I want to check
    puts "Copyright is missing or written in a wrong format"
  end
end
file.close
```

This code checks for the copyright pattern and prints `"Copyright is missing.."` for every line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use file.read to store the file into a single string.

```
file = File.open("file_tobe_checked", "r")
contents = file.read

if (contents =~ /Copyright \W+ \d\d\d\d/).nil?  # the pattern I want to check
    puts "Copyright is missing or written in a wrong format"
end

file.close
```

See IO.read for more information. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-read

warning: This works well if you know you have a fairly smallish file and you know the copyright will be near the end.

Comment: If you intend to slurp the file, `contents = file.read("fname")` might be easier. Also, you could use `unless contents =~...` without `.nil`.

Comment: I wanted to use File.open because I will be checking for white spaces line by line right after I check for copyright in the while loop. You got any more suggestions?

Comment: You can use File.open, no problem. Then just call file.read to slurp in the file to a string. (as opposed to file.get)

Comment: I meant `File.read("fname")` (i.e., capital "F").  @Jeff, if you'll be slurping, wouldn't `File#read` be easier than `f = File.open`..`f.read`..`f.close`?

Answer (score 0):

You're close:

```
found_copyright = false

file = file.open("file_tobe_checked", "r")  #opened the file I wanted to check
while (line=file.get && !found_copyright)
  found_copyright = found_copyright || (line =~ /Copyright \W+ \d\d\d\d/)
end
file.close 

unless found_copyright
  puts "Copyright is missing or written in a wrong format"
end
```